# How might one cold-email a manager who one had contact with a while ago

Tags: job-search, applications, email

I am currently applying for jobs.

Around this time last year, while I was still in school, I was introduced by my friend to a manager at a company, say, in **Field A**. Although at the time, there was no job available, the manager expressed an interest in potentially hiring me in the future if a position became available. However, soon afterwards, I got a job in **Field B** that was quite unrelated to **Field A**. I haven't really kept in touch with this manager.

However, having worked at my current job for almost a year, I've come to realize that what I am doing really isn't what I would like to continue doing, which is why I am now applying for jobs. I want to cold-email the manager about potential opportunities, but I am not sure how I might approach him - given that I haven't kept in touch with him. I have never cold-emailed potential employers, so I don't know how I might approach this. Any advice/suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

One possible email:

> Dear Manager,
>
> We exchanged email and phone calls earlier last year regarding possible job opportunities at your company. I later took a job at CurrentCompany. However I would like to pursue a new career path as I believe my skills and mindset are more suitable for Field A. I would like to know if there is any potential new job openings in the near future. I would love to discuss with you how I might contribute to the work at your company
>
> Best,
>
> Saccades

I wonder (1) whether I should mention my friend's name and (2) whether I should mention my current job.

Comment: Give us an example of the sort of email you think would be suitable to send.

Comment: @TerenceEden: Added :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always worth reminding people *how* they know you.  I think the email you've drafted looks good, but I'd start it with:

> Last year Joe Bloggs introduced us to each other.

Or similar.  People receive so many emails, giving them a little nudge can help.

Comment: even better if you can add a where - _Last year at _______ Joe Bloggs introduced us_